# ¿Cómo se sabe si se ha salido de una ventana modal en bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

¿Existe una validación o algo que indique que si una ventana modal en bootstrap se cierra el sistema sepa y recargue o se sincronice lo que se hizo mientras estaba trabajando en la ventana modal?

Answer (score 1):

Debes enlazar una función al evento al hidden

```
$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', mifunction)
```